# How to append client-side scripts to page in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm starting project ts, node, express.
Is there a way to add typescript files to html/ejs that run on client side (so i have access to document e.t.c., just like in regular js script)?

So it would be something like:

- Node server with express that returns html pages and handles users sign in/up requests.
- Adding, deleting, changing elements in html on user's activity handles in scripts on client side.

I would appreciate pointing on what I misunderstood in whole node, express conception if I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link for detailed explaination:
[Serving html from express](https://heynode.com/tutorial/process-user-login-form-expressjs/)

You can basically serve html pages from express.
On root request handler you can server index.html

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{res.render('index.html');}
```

Now in the index.html page have a link to /index route example:

```
<a href="/login">
```

Now, on server code have a route handler

```
app.get('/login', (req, res)=>{res.render('login.html');}
```

login.html can now have a form with action

```
<form action="/signin" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Now, on server code have a route handler

```
app.post('signin', (req, res)=>{//handle logic here});
```

Comment: Ok, I've understood post request.
But if we'd say I have a view - index.html with a div. And i have a script.ts file that has some event listeners. How do I append this script to my html?

Comment: I'm not sure about TS as it needs to be compiled first as you can't run TS directly on the browser , but js file you can simply add js files like you would normally using script tag. Keep you js files in express_project_path/public/js/demo.js

Comment: To use TS files, I guess you'll have to use tsc and in package.json write a command (like there is "start":"node index.js") to compile ts into js n then start the server. Though I'm not sure of this setup sorry ;(

Comment: oh, thanks. So i’ll just add folder ‘public’ to express static and then i can refer to files inside this folder? Like <script sec=“public/index.js”>